# total count % variance for months in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i need 3 columns

```
count   period    variance    
50      JAN        0%
100     FEB        100%
```

i am using this query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sale) AS cnt, TO_CHAR("date", 'MON-YYYY') AS Period
  FROM BETA_MAN_POS_mth
 WHERE "date" BETWEEN date'2020-01-01' AND date'2020-01-31'
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR("date", 'MON-YYYY')
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sale) AS cnt, TO_CHAR("date", 'MON-YYYY') AS Period
  FROM BETA_MAN_POS_mth
 WHERE "date" BETWEEN date'2020-02-01' AND date'2020-02-28'
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR("date", 'MON-YYYY')
```

how to find the % diff for month into the new column called "variance"

Comment: i need 3 columns

count |  period |   variance

50    |  jan   |     0%
100   |  FEB  |      100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()` analytic function :

```
WITH b2 AS
(
SELECT TO_CHAR("date",'YYYYMM') AS period0, -- in order to use for ordering
       TO_CHAR("date",'YYYY-MON') AS period, -- in order to display month abbreviations
       COUNT(DISTINCT sale) As cnt
  FROM BETA_MAN_POS_mth
GROUP BY TO_CHAR("date",'YYYYMM'), TO_CHAR("date",'YYYY-MON') 
)
SELECT cnt ,period, 
       100*(cnt-lag(cnt,1,cnt) over (order by period0))
       /lag(cnt,1,cnt) over (order by period0)
       as "variance(%)"
  FROM b2
 ORDER BY period0
```

to get the value of an individual column for a previous row.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=39f7ed87b4cd6bc73ab7761b781f542d)</kbd>

Comment: I need variance for last two months only and should be dynamically

Comment: what do you mean by *dynamically* ?  @kirtichoudhary